# How can I set a column in the footerdata with a dynamic name?

Tags: jqgrid, footer

How can I set a column in the footerdata with a dynamic name?

Instead of doing:

```
grid.footerData('set', { Total: total.toFixed(1) });
```

I would like to do something like:

```
var colName = 'Total'
grid.footerData('set', { colName: total.toFixed(1) });
```

But this obviously is not working... How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object

```js
{ Total: total.toFixed(1) }
```

has `Total` property. You can create the property dynamically by usage `[]`:

```js
var colName = 'Total', options = {};
options[colName] = total.toFixed(1);
grid.footerData('set', options);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Very helpful!